# Undefined variable:visiteur in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

Helloo , i want to add comment into a blog with showing the name of the patient who added , with using session , so i get this error : `Undefined variable: visiteur`

This is the **commentcontroller.php** :

```
public function store  (blog $getid , Request $request)
{
    $visitor=patient::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get() ;
    $patient_id=$request->session()->get('patient_id');
     comment::create([
        'body' =>request('body'),
        'blog_id'=> $getid->id,
        'patient_id'=>$patient_id
    ]);

     return back()->with(['visiteur'=>$visitor]);
}
}
```

This is the view : **show.blade.php**

```
 <div class="card-body" >
  @foreach ($showme->comments as $comment)
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
      <p style="font-size:15px;">{{$comment->body}}</p>
        @foreach ($visiteur as $viis)
        @if ($comment->patient_id == $viis->id)
         <p> {{$comment->patient_id}}</p>
        @endif
        @endforeach
      <footer class="blockquote-footer"> {{$comment->created_at}} <cite title="Source Title"> </cite></footer>
    </blockquote>
    @endforeach
  </div>
  <!-- si le patient est connceter -->
  @if(Session::has('log_in'))
    <div class="card-block">
   <form method="POST" action="/blog/{{$showme->id}}/store" >
   @csrf
   <div class="form-group">
   <label> Commentaire </label> </br>
   <textarea name="body"  rows="3" cols="80" cols="form-control"></textarea> </br>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Ajouter commentaire</button>
</div>
  </form>
</div>
@endif
```

And finally this is the **web.php**

```
Route::Post('/store' , 'patientcontroller@store');
```

This is the Patient controller :

```
public function welcome(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'mail' => 'required|email',
            'mdp' => 'required',
        ]);

        // since email is unique. no need to grab all data
        $patient = patient::where('Login', $request->input('mail'))->first();


        // if patient exists
        if ($patient) {
            // check hashed password
            // assuming $patient->Password hashed
            if (Hash::check($request->input('mdp'), $patient->Password)) {
                //session 
                $request->session()->put('patient_id', $patient->Nom);
                $request->session()->put('log_in', true);
                return redirect ('index');
            }
        }
        return back()->withErrors([
            'message' => 'Emails or password not correct!',
        ]);
    }
```

i want to show the name of the user who add the comment but he show me only the ID

Comment: In general, you are not passing the variable `visiteur` to the view. Check the places where you load the `show.blade.php`.

Comment: another problem appear , he show me only the id of patient and i want him to show me the name !

Comment: If the user is logged in, the generic details of the user should be there in session. If you can't find it in session, you should query the DB to get the details of user.

Comment: @HarishST already do it but the same thing , i'm going to add the patient controller to my post

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
return back()->with(['visiteur', $visitor]);
```